# $a_{n+1}=\frac{{a_n}^2+2}{2a_n}$ Proof that the sequence is monotonically decreasing.

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, monotone-functions

I am trying to find the limit of a recursively defined sequence:

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{{a_n}^2+2}{2a_n}$$ for $a_1=1$

To do this I need to first show that the sequence is monotonically decreasing so I tried to prove this using induction:

Base case: $n=1,$    $a_2 = \frac{3}{2} \ge \frac{17}{12} = a_3.$

Assume $a_{n+1} \ge a_{n+2}$ for some $n \in \mathbf{N}.$

For $n+1:$ $$a_{n+2}=\frac{{a_{n+1}}^2+2}{2a_{n+1}} \le a_{n+1}$$
$${a_{n+1}}^2+2 \le (2a_{n+1})^2 \tag{1}$$

For $a_{n+3}$ I get
$$\frac{{a_{n+1}}^4+12{a_{n+1}}^2+4}{4{a_{n+1}}^3+8a_{n+1}}$$
I know I have to use $(1)$ to show
$$\frac{{a_{n+1}}^2+2}{2a_{n+1}} \ge \frac{{a_{n+1}}^4+12{a_{n+1}}^2+4}{4{a_{n+1}}^3+8a_{n+1}}$$
I don't really know how to get here though.

Comment: $a_2 - a_1 = \frac{3}{2} - 1 = \frac{1}{2} > 0$, so the sequence is not monotonically decreasing.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I noticed, however the exercise pretty much assumes it to be monotonically decreasing so I am confused.

Comment: This an algorithm to produce $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = \sqrt{2}$

Comment: [The accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2998480/386889) in the following duplicate answers your question much more simply than the answers below: [Show that $x_{n+1} = \frac{2+x_n^2}{2x_n}$ is a decreasing sequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998415/show-that-x-n1-frac2x-n22x-n-is-a-decreasing-sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an elementary solution i.e. without derivative. Rearranging the equation yields the following quadratic equation:

$$
a_{n}^{2}-2a_{n+1}a_{n}+2=0
$$

From the initial relation, it is apparent that the sequence is positive real so obviously the equation must have real solutions so the discriminant is non-negative i.e.

$$
4a_{n+1}^{2}-8\geq 0
\phantom{x}
\iff
\phantom{x}
a_{n+1}^{2}\geq 2
$$

From the last inequality and using the fact that $a_{n+1}\geq 0\phantom{x}\forall\phantom{x}n$:

$$
2a_{n+1}^{2}\geq a_{n+1}^{2}+2
\phantom{x}
\implies
\phantom{x}
a_{n+1}\geq\frac{a_{n+1}^{2}+2}{2a_{n+1}}=a_{n+2}
$$

Therefore, we have shown that the sequence is decreasing starting from $a_{2}$ and it is bounded below at $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Please do not rush to answer such a FAQ. Link to a duplicate instead.